# Loop using Vlookup application in VBA is causing Excel to Not respond

Tags: vba, vlookup

I'm using three Workbooks. My Current workbook, The database workbook (DB_Wkb), the Document to change ( Doc_Wkb) and my current macro file.

I'm using vLookup to compare the ID, and get the name from the database The problem is that it works fine, but it takes a lot of time and Excel stops responding. I believe the use of vlookup is what makes my macro to take so long.

```
    Dim Doc_Wkb As Workbook 'Document
    Dim DB_Wkb As Workbook 'Database
    Set Doc_Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Doc_Path)
    Doc_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Cells.Select 'sheet_name=Sheet of the Document
    Selection.UnMerge
    Doc_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Range("A5:S" & Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=16, Header:=xlYes
    Set DB_Wkb = Workbooks.Open(DB_Path)
    Dim Str As String
    Dim Cont_Doc As Double
    P = 6 ' P Declared in Module
    Cont_DB = DB_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_name_2).Range("B:F") ' Sheet_name_2 = sheetname of DB
    While Not IsEmpty(Doc_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Cells(P, 5))
        Cont_Doc = Doc_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Cells(P, 5)
        store = Application.VLookup(Cont_Doc, Cont_DB, 5, False)
        Doc_Wkb.Worksheets(Sheet_Name).Cells(P, 20) = store
        P = P + 1
    Wend
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured out an alternative. Using DoEvents solves this problem. Meanwhile a progress bar can be used for the looks.